# "you will have it all to yourself again." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

This sentence is from Modern Family 
I want to know meaning of this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the "it" in this sentence refers to, but having something all to yourself just means you have exclusive ownership over it, it is yours and does not belong to anyone else. Generally it means that some sort of selfish action payed off, but possibly at the cost of companionship: if they have it all to themself, they have no one to share it with and are alone.

Comment: +1 for **exclusive** but "ownership" is not necessarily involved, and there is not generally a selfish action involved.  A person could have a sofa in a hotel *all to herself* in the off season, say.